# NSMutableArrays - can I do this?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

In my app, the singleton class (SharedData) allocates memory for a NSMutableArray:

```
[self sharedMutableArray] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Class A populates the this sharedMutableArray:

```
NSObject *obj = [NSObject alloc] init];
[sharedMutableArray  addObject];
obj = nil;
```

Class B does this - and that's my question:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = sharedMutableArray;
       ... uses the tmpArray locally
[tmpArray removeAllObjects];
tmpArray = nil;
```

This is an inherited code and my hunch is that this is a NO-NO.  Can some one confirm that assigning nil to tmpArray will release memory for sharedMutableArray also.... I guess the author wanted to release tmpArray only...

Comment: As the others said, setting a pointer to nil only sets the pointer to nil.  A pointer is not the object to which it points, any more than your address on a postcard is your house.  Destroying the postcard will not destroy the house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning `nil` to tmpArray only sets your pointer to the object to `nil`. It does not affect the object itself (or its lifecycle) at all. In this case, setting the objects you've created to `nil` does nothing, since their variable declaration is in local scope - if you want the objects to be deallocated from memory you need to send them `release` before setting the *pointer* to the object to `nil`.

However, sending `removeAllObjects` **is** affecting your original sharedArray, because you didn't copy the array, you simply set a new pointer to point to the 'singleton'. You probably want this:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sharedMutableArray];
```

You won't need to use `removeAllObjects` in the above case because it will be autorelease'd. I suggest you read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using ARC, and am not sure how I'd go about copying contents of sharedMutableArray to tmpArray - should I use for(...) loop? - like - for(NSObject *elem in sharedMutableArray) { [tmpArray addObject:elem]; } ??

Comment: There's no issue with using `arrayWithArray:` with ARC - it does all the copying for you. However, you don't seem to understand the concept of ownership completely - an array is just a list of pointers to other objects. Even if you copied the list of pointers to a new list of pointers, the objects pointed by those pointers don't change (ie, they're not copied).

Comment: The design is to populate the localArray from the sharedArray, use it and then discard if - leaving the shareData in tact.  Some other operation will manage sharedData.

Comment: So you want to do a deep copy. Read this: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/May/msg00172.html

Answer (score 0):

`tmpArray` is a pointer, and it's initialized to point to the same mutable array that sharedMutableArray points to. For that reason, the line:

```
[tmpArray removeAllObjects];
```

will empty out the array, and anyone using `sharedMutableArray` will see that change. In other words, the assignment

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = sharedMutableArray;
```

doesn't make a copy of the array itself, it only copies the pointer. Any messages you send using that pointer will go to the shared array. Likewise, assigning `nil` to `tmpArray` sets the pointer `tmpArray`, but doesn't do anything to the array itself.

Finally, setting a *variable* to `nil` never releases memory. Setting a *property* to nil, on the other hand, will release memory under some conditions (e.g. when the property is declared to retain its contents). You're setting a variable here, not a property, so there's no chance that the array will be released.

Comment: thanks - Good expalanation.  If tmpArray was an iVar and had property, would tmpArray=nil release the memory for sharedMutableArray?

Comment: "Finally, setting a variable to nil *never* releases memory" <-- sans ARC of course (I know that's what you meant)

Comment: No, but `self.tmpArray` would if the property was `retain`.